# How can I convert a sentence to an array of words?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

From this string:

```
$input = "Some terms with spaces between";
```

how can I produce this array?

```
$output = ['Some', 'terms', 'with', 'spaces', 'between'];
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use [`explode`](http://docs.php.net/explode), [`split`](http://docs.php.net/split) or [`preg_split`](http://docs.php.net/preg_split).

`explode` uses a fixed string:

```
$parts = explode(' ', $string);
```

while `split` and `preg_split` use a regular expression:

```
$parts = split(' +', $string);
$parts = preg_split('/ +/', $string);
```

An example where the regular expression based splitting is useful:

```
$string = 'foo   bar';  // multiple spaces
var_dump(explode(' ', $string));
var_dump(split(' +', $string));
var_dump(preg_split('/ +/', $string));
```

Comment: The split function is deprecated in php 5.3 so use explode or preg_split instead

Answer (score 11):

```
$parts = explode(" ", $str);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print_r(str_word_count("this is a sentence", 1));
```

Results in:

```
Array ( [0] => this [1] => is [2] => a [3] => sentence )
```

Answer (score 4):

Just thought that it'd be worth mentioning that the regular expression Gumbo posted—although it will more than likely suffice for most—may not catch all cases of white-space. An example: Using the regular expression in the approved answer on the string below:

```
$sentence = "Hello                       my name    is   peter string           splitter";
```

Provided me with the following output through print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => my
    [2] => name
    [3] => is
    [4] => peter
    [5] => string
    [6] =>      splitter
)
```

Where as, when using the following regular expression:

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence);
```

Provided me with the following (desired) output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => my
    [2] => name
    [3] => is
    [4] => peter
    [5] => string
    [6] => splitter
)
```

Hope it helps anyone stuck at a similar hurdle and is confused as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Just a question, but are you trying to make json out of the data? If so, then you might consider something like this:

```
return json_encode(explode(' ', $inputString));
```