# Mysql PHP find name in a text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pattern-matching, match

I would like to know if there is a fast way to get a row like this:

```
Name (Database comumn) would be a database like |ID|Name|Age|Gender|
```

Not in table:

```
Text (long string)
```

Names:

```
John Smith
Jack Stone
Brian Woods
Text: "Someone was going to go to John Smith but instead went to Brian Woods. Why would he do that to John Smith?"
```

And the query should return "John Smith" matches 2 times, "Brian Woods" matches 1 time

How do you get a thing that does this fast?

```
$text = "Someone was going to go to John Smith but instead went to Brian Woods. Why would he do that to John Smith?";
$query = $mysql("SELECT * FROM persons");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
if(preg_match("/".$r["Name"]."/", $text))
{
$matches[$r["name"]]+=1;
}
}
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.However, you should give your inoperative code.

Comment: added it, sorry it does work but in a database of 3000 records this is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the `like` command?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM persons
WHERE name like '%John Smith%';
```

If you start to get a lot of data (and 3000 rows is not a lot of data), you might want to look into full text indexing.

Comment: I don't need to find it in the database I need to know if and how many tines names are mentioned in a text. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @MyName . . . Then just use `count(*)` instead of `*`.

Comment: the text is not in the database

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long your sentence is (compared to the amount of Names you are searching for you can flip the search direction within the following method)

You can [convert your sentence into an array of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618729/how-to-convert-a-sentence-to-an-array-of-words-in-php) (strings). Now loop through the words, concatenating each with the next and search with `in_array()` within the name list from your database.